# What is the actual amount of money lost to corporate tax evasion and avoidance in the UK?

Tags: taxation

I find this topic confusing, because there are so many figures out there from seemingly credible sources. You hear politicians using figures to either attack current policy or defend it. Many people disagree with the governments own figures.

So I would like to know, without any of the politics, what is the actual, or closest to actual figure of how much money is lost through corporate tax evasion and avoidance in the UK?

Please cite sources and if you can; reasons why the figure you provide is correct or as close to correct as possible.

Comment: There may be a correct figure or best estimate for evasion, which is generally understood to mean illegal non-payment or under-payment.  But when people refer to avoidance they usually mean managing tax affairs in a way which is not illegal but which they consider wrong - it's an evaluative term - so the question as worded cannot have a definitive answer.